Can you install and configure a vSphere cluster having ONLY the ILO (or DRAC) interfaces accessible?
Please bear with me through the lengthy explanation. It is a bit of an odd situation that needs some clarification.
This question came up during a discussion with a customer that has a high-security isolated network on which an VMWare ESX cluster (small, 2 nodes, about 10 VM's, nothing needing really high performance) needs to be setup.
That network has NO connection to the outside world whatsoever.
Their local IT people have a workstation available in that network from which they can (re-)configure LAN and the iSCSI SAN (already in place) as needed. (Or bring in software on USB stick if needed.)
Only the ILO (or DRAC) interfaces (they could go either HPE or Dell for the servers) could possibly, for the duration of initial setup and configuration, be temporarily connected to the regular LAN.
The other NICs on both nodes (4x 10 Gb/s per node) will be connected to that isolated network with iSCSI vlan, VMotion vlan and serverlan provided as tagged vlan's to each of those NICs.
They need an external consultant to do inital setup and configuration (they can operate an existing ESX, but setting one up from scratch is a bit beyond them).
As mentioned, that consultant can be given access to the ILO's, but having him/her come on-site and physically work inside the isolated LAN is highly problematic due to a mandatory (and very obnoxious) screening procedure that will take months and is very costly. (Their normal IT service provider refuses to put their own people through the screening. The competitors do the same.)
For hardware repairs a service tech is allowed to work on the hardware, under supervision of the local IT people, but as soon as it gets into the realm of software and configuration even that isn't permitted.
So, they asked me, if doing the initial setup using only the ILO's for access is feasible.
I'm not that in-depth familiar with ESX configuration myself and I've never been in such a position before, so I honestly don't know, but I'm very curious if such a thing can be done.
So, can anyone enlighten me, if this is possible?
PS. If it can't be done I will probably recommend them to setup a temporary network with the same vlan configuration and ip-ranges. Have the consultant do the configuration on that and then physically move both ESX nodes into the real network. The iSCSI bit is gong to be problematic though as the SAN part can't easily be faked. May have to rent some SAN equipment for that.

That might depend a bit on the actual server model at hand.
I've personally installed ESXi on a DL325 G10 entirely from remote (w/ iLO 5 Advanced) as disaster recovery PoC. The only local work was rack installation and cabling, just its base MAC (for WoL) and ILO password was required. So it's definitely feasible with current models.
We've also tested Dell models, so it's not just a HPE thing.

If the iLO or iDRAC have the correct license that allows for a remote console then yes, you should be able to set up ESXi remotely.
